# How can I plot probability values from different lists on top of one another, over an entire range of X values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 5 different lists y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3 and y_4 : Each of which contain 450120 probability values. The corresponding values of each of the lists add up to 1, i.e, y_0[n] + y_1[n] + y_2[n] + y_3[n] + y_4[n] = 1 for any 'n'.

The X axis contains the indices or the time steps, which are numbers sequentially ranging from 0 to 450119.
I want to plot the Y values such that the corresponding probability values or entries of the 5 lists at a given index are plotted on top of one another in different colors.
For example: If y_0[0] = 0.2 , y_1[0] = 0.3, y_2[0] = 0.1, y_3[0] = 0.3, y_4[0] = 0.1.
So at x=0, I want the following:
y_0[0] to be plotted in red from 0 to 0.2 , y_1[0] to be plotted in green from 0.2 to 0.5, y_2[0] to be plotted in yellow from 0.5 to 0.6, y_3[0] to be plotted in blue from 0.6 to 0.9, y_4[0] to be plotted in pink from 0.9 to 1.

And this must repeat for all x values from 0 to 450119.

Currently, I am getting many blank spaces in the plot, as well as many overlaps. Class C5 is not visible at all.[image]

```py
def plotAllClassesInOne(y_indices,y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,filename):
    plt.xlabel('Time in seconds')
    plt.ylabel('P(Y|X)')
    plt.plot(y_indices, plott(y_0), 'y',label='C1')
    plt.plot(y_indices, plott([sum(x) for x in zip(y_0,y_1)]), 'r',label='C2')
    plt.plot(y_indices, plott([sum(x) for x in zip(y_0,y_1,y_2)]), 'g',label='C3')
    plt.plot(y_indices, plott([sum(x) for x in zip(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)]), 'b',label='C4')
    plt.plot(y_indices, plott([sum(x) for x in zip(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)]), 'k',label='C5') 
    plt.legend()
    fig1 = plt.gcf()
    fig1.savefig(filename)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that there is no monitor with 400000 pixels in width, and hence not all points can be shown anyways?!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
def plotAllClassesInOne(y_indices,y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,filename):

    length = y_0.shape[0]
    xaxis = np.arange(0, length)
    c1_base = np.zeros(length)
    c1_height = y_0

    c2_base = c1_height
    c2_height = c2_base + y_1

    c3_base = c2_height
    c3_height = c3_base + y_2

    c4_base = c3_height
    c4_height = c4_base + y_3

    c5_base = c4_height
    c5_height = c5_base + y_4

    plt.xlabel('Time in seconds')
    plt.ylabel('P(Y|X)')
    ax.fill_between(xaxis, c1_base, c1_height, label='C1', color='y')
    ax.fill_between(xaxis, c2_base, c2_height, label='C2', color='r')
    ax.fill_between(xaxis, c3_base, c3_height, label='C3', color='g')
    ax.fill_between(xaxis, c4_base, c4_height, label='C4', color='b')
    ax.fill_between(xaxis, c5_base, c5_height, label='C5', color='k')
    plt.legend()
    fig1 = plt.gcf()
    fig1.savefig(filename)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Spot on @jimijimjim. 
Thanks a ton man!! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I tried, but this is the error I get : 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

My reputation level is 11 currently, but your answer has been upvoted with a green tick. It'll reflect once my level touches 15.

Comment: No worries, upvoting and accepting are two separate processes. There should be a greyed out check-mark, and if you click it, it will mark the answer as accepted. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235